# Curious probability problem

Tags: probability-theory

Segment [0, 1] is split into three pieces by two random points*. What would be the mathematical expectation of the length of the shortest part?

I and my fellow student have two different solutions and came to two different answers:

(1) $\frac{1}{9}$

(2) $\ln\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{2}$

What would be the proper solution and right answer?

(*) Points are chosen independently from a uniform distribution on [0, 1] segment.

**My solution.**

(1) It's obvious, that the maximal length of the shortest part is $\frac{1}{3}$.

(2) It's safe to do all calculations if the middle part is the shortest one. For the leftmost/rightmost part all reasoning  is symmetrical and won't alter the result.

(3) For fixed length $\lambda$ the probability of the middle part being shortest is:

$\frac{1-3\lambda}{1-\lambda}$

because the middle piece start point can vary in $[0, 1-\lambda]$ range, but for it to be the shortest piece range is bound to $(\lambda, 1-2\lambda)$.

(4) Using the formula to compute mathematical expectation of continuous variable:

$E = \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{3}}\frac{1-3\lambda}{1-\lambda}\lambda d\lambda \approx 0.022 $

**When my reasoning went wrong?**

Comment: @Harry49 Updated the topic. Two random points are independently chosen from a uniform distribution on [0, 1] segment. Split is defined by those points.

Comment: If by "lowest part" you mean the shortest of the three segments, then the answer is $\frac{1}{9}$.

Comment: @carmichael561 Could you tell how to get $\frac{1}{9}$? Also will publish my reasoning to check what's wrong.

Comment: @carmichael561 Could you tell how you get $\frac{1}{9}$ and check my solution, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My main issue with your solution is point (2), though point (3) is also not entirely clear to me. Here is my approach:

Let $M$ be the length of the smallest of the three pieces. If $0\leq m\leq \frac{1}{3}$, then
$$ \mathbb{P}(M>m)=\mathbb{P}(X>m,Y-X>m,1-Y>m)+\mathbb{P}(Y>m,X-Y>m,1-X>m)$$
$$=2\mathbb{P}(X>m,Y-X>m,1-Y>m)$$
with the last equality following by symmetry.

If $X>m,Y-X>m$, and $1-Y>m$ then it follows that $m<X<1-2m$ and $X+m<Y<1-m$. Therefore
$$ \mathbb{P}(M>m)=2\int_{m}^{1-2m}\int_{x+m}^{1-m}\;dydx=\int_{m}^{1-2m}[2(1-2m)-2x]\;dx$$
$$ =\Big[2(1-2m)x-x^2\Big]_{m}^{1-2m}=1-6m+9m^2 $$
Therefore
$$ \mathbb{P}(M\leq m)=1-\mathbb{P}(M>m)=6m-9m^2$$
for $0\leq m\leq \frac{1}{3}$, and differentiating with respect to $m$ we obtain
$$ f_M(m)=6-18m$$
for $0\leq m\leq \frac{1}{3}$. Hence
$$ \mathbb{E}[M]=\int_0^{\frac{1}{3}}6m-18m^2\;dm=\Big[3m^2-6m^3\Big]_{0}^{\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{2}{9}=\frac{1}{9}$$

Comment: Very clear solution. It seems to me I have to revise probability theory for continuous variables. I was somewhat totally wrong in the very approach.